# How can I type in a textarea and have that text be added to a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, contenteditable, keyup

I have a `<div contenteditable="true">` and a `<textarea>` on my page. I need to get the text that is typed in the textarea to be displayed in the div, while keeping the text that was already in the div. I already kind of achieved that with a `keyup` function on the `textarea` but it is not working properly. I believe the problem must be having the `contenteditable` text variable updated with each `keyup`. I tried changing the scope of `value1`, making it a global variable instead, but it still does not work. Any help?

This is my code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3x9ovwh/)

```js
$(".secondary").keyup(function () {
  var value1 = $(".original").html();
  var value2 = $(".secondary").val();
  $(".original").html(value1 + value2);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Content Editable:</p>
<div class="original" contenteditable></div>

<br><br>

<p>Text Area:</p>
<textarea class="secondary"></textarea>
```

So, if you type "Foo" in the `contenteditable` and "bar" in the `textarea`, the text in the `contenteditable` should be "foobar".

Also, if the last character in the `contenteditable` is a space, typing in the `textarea` will add a `<br>` to the `contenteditable`. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `keyup`, I'd prefer to use `input` event handler. Try out the snippet :

```js
$(".secondary").on('input', function(event) {
  var val = $('.original').text();
  $('.original').text(val + event.originalEvent.data);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Content Editable:</p>
<div class="original" contenteditable></div>

<br><br>

<p>Text Area:</p>
<textarea class="secondary"></textarea>
```

Comment: Still not what I need (my bad for not giving enough detail), but it does solve the problem I presented. Just before I accept this answer, can you please help me out with the undesired line break that is added when I go from typing in the `contenteditable` to the `textarea`?

Comment: @MikeMichaels I have updated the code. Have a look :)

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Better you use change event instead of keyup:

```
$(".secondary").change(function () {
    var value1 = $(".original").html();
    var value2 = $(".secondary").val();
    $(".original").html(value1 + value2);
    /*Reset text area*/
    $(".secondary").val('');
});
```

Comment: This does add the text to the `contenteditable` properly. However, the reason I was using `keyup` was to let the user see each character appear, as they are typed, which is really a must because, later on, the textarea will not be visible to the user.